# Heroku Array Unshift Method Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a working rails app on my local machine. I updated my Heroku and started to test it. One of my views requires the controller to add elements to an array using unshift.

When I go to this view on the web, I get an error `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

I went into `$heroku logs` and the most recent errors are:

```
2014-02-28T02:08:26.650021+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `unshift' for #<ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::Attribute:0x007fe57862f588>):
2014-02-28T02:08:26.650021+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:32:in `show'
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

my controller function looks like this:

```
@user.daily = @user.daily.unshift(day)
```

@user.daily is a serialized array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mhsmith21, if day is an object and if you are rails 4+ then my suggestion is to use build instead of unshift.
If you are using unshift to add the object on first position then use build and reverse the array.

As unshift does not work for `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`.